# Send data to previous JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

I am working with JFrames, I have a main JFrame, which calls for a second JFrame (jFrame2 for example). I need at that jFrame2 has 9 buttons with images within each button (UP HERE ALL PERFECT). Then when in the jFrame2 press a button, close the jFrame2 and send a string to jFrame1. the jFrame1 must be waiting for the end jFrame2 to receive the string that sends the jFrame2, and since the jFrame1 send a JSON to the server with that string.

This is my example code:

```
////// class jFrame1 //////

public class jFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame{

   public JTextField JTextField1; 
   public JTextField JTextField2; 
   public JTextField JTextField3; 
   private JButton jButton1;

   .....

}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   jFrame2 regPack = new jFrame2();
   regPack.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   regPack.setVisible(true);

   //HERE I WANT THE PROGRAM RESPONSE TO WAIT CLOSE AND CONTINUE RUNNING JFrame

   ....
}



////// class jFrame2 //////

public class jFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame{

   private JButton jButton1;
   private JButton jButton2;

   public jFrame2(){
   }

   .....

}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   //HERE I WANT TO SEND A STRING ON JFRAME1 BEFORE CLOSING THIS JFRAME2
   this.dispose();
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   //HERE I WANT TO SEND A STRING ON JFRAME1 BEFORE CLOSING THIS JFRAME2
   this.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Honestly, just use a modal dialog...

Comment: yes, but I need to put in the jFrame2 or JDialog 9 buttons with a big image on each button. JDialog can be configured with 9 buttons each with a picture and some actions?

Comment: Short answer yes, long answer is it might need some tweaking depending on the size of the images...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it so that `frame2` has a method (getter) that `frame1` can retrieve the value that was set.

Change it so that `frame2` is a modal `JDialog`. This will cause you code to stop at the point that the `JDialog` is made visible, but allow the rest of the UI to remain responsive. When the dialog is closed, the code (in `frame1`) will continue executing and you can retrieve the value from `frame2` via the fore mentioned getter.

Take a look at [How to make dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details...

Comment: but I need to put in the jFrame2 or JDialog 9 buttons with a big image on each button. JDialog can be configured with 9 buttons each with a picture and some actions?

Comment: JDialog is a type of window, so anything a JFrame can do, a JDialog can do (can't be maximised though) and it can be modal, blocking until it is closed. Check the link, it'll explains more

Comment: Thank you very much friend, I´m going to check this link :-D

Answer (score 2):

u may try like this:

```
public class jFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame{
  // ur code
  private String string;

  public void setString(String string) {
    this.string = string;
  }
}

public class jFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame{
  // ur code
  private jFrame1 frame1; // <-- note its jFrame1 not JFrame

  public jFrame2(jFrame1 frame1) { // <-- note its jFrame1 not JFrame
    this.frame1 = frame1;
  }

  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    this.frame1.setString("wat u wana send here");
    this.dispose();
  }

  // so on
}
```

Comment: This is just my opinion, but exposing frame1 to frame2 gives to much power to frame2 to do things with the frame it shouldn't be allowed to do or know it can do. Frame2 should do just the job it's designed for and nothing more

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I agree with u, we can make jFrame1 to implement a interface say Setter with only method setString(String) and construct jFrame2 having constructor like public jFrame2(Setter setter)

Comment: That's certainly a solution

Comment: @Arvind but, how I can make just wait jFrame1 response jFrame2?

Comment: @Despotars, u may make ur jFrame2 extend JDialog incase u don't want user to focus on jFrame1 until jFrame2 is closed.

Comment: yes @Arvind, but the buttons I can not charge the same as if it were a JFrame, do you have some example?

Comment: @Despotars, u may [refer this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ASimpleModalDialog.htm)

Comment: @Arvind one question, I have this error: "parent is not public in Component; cannot be accessed from outside package" when I write this sentence:

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    setVisible(false);
    parent.setString("this is a test");
    dispose(); 
  }
Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the solution is quite simple. Edit your classes as follows:

```
public class jframe1 extends JFrame{
    .
    .
    private String response;
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        jFrame2 regPack = new jFrame2(**this**);  // pass the current reference of the frame
    .
    .
    .
    }

    public setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

public class jframe2 extends JFrame {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    jframe1 jf1;
    jframe2() {
    }

    jframe2(jframe1 jf1) {
        this.jf1 = jf1;
    }


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        jf1.setResponse("this is the response"); // set the response here
        this.dispose();
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is just my opinion, but exposing frame1 to frame2 gives to much power to frame2 to do things with the frame it shouldn't be allowed to do or know it can do. Frame2 should do just the job it's designed for and nothing more

Answer (score 1):

You can have a parameterised constructor for JFrame2 where it accepts an instance of JFrame1

```
public JFrame2(JFrame1 frame) {...}
```

JFrame2 can have a variable to store the value of JFrame1.
When button is pressed, you can call method in JFrame1 as follows:

```
frame1.setString("...");
```

You can pass instance of JFrame1 to JFrame2

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   jFrame2 regPack = new jFrame2(this);
   regPack.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   regPack.setVisible(true);

   //HERE I WANT THE PROGRAM RESPONSE TO WAIT CLOSE AND CONTINUE RUNNING JFrame

   ....
}
```

Comment: This is just my opinion, but exposing frame1 to frame2 gives to much power to frame2 to do things with the frame it shouldn't be allowed to do or know it can do. Frame2 should do just the job it's designed for and nothing more