# Java - Pausing a method until a button is pressed in a different class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, pause

Alright, so I'm working on a project for university right now.
Basicly a card game, and in this case an editor to create your own decks.
When the user trys to save a deck, the programm checks if a file with that name already exists. If so, a notification will open up.
The user can either confirm, or cancel (pressing a button in the notification sets a boolean to either true or false)

I now need a way to pause the saveDeck Method, until the user pressed a button in the notification window. Everything I found so far, searching the internet was either about timers (which won't help with my problem), or explained in a way I didn`t understand the slightest bit.

Anyways, here is the code  I have so far, regarding my problem:
Deck Class:

```
public class Deck{
[...]
private String name = "";
private boolean overwrite = false;
[...]
public void saveDeck(){
    if (this.name.equals("")){
        ErrorWindow error = new ErrorWindow(3); 
        return;
    }else{
    }
    String deckpath = "Decks\\" + this.name +".txt";
    File deck = new File(deckpath);
    if (deck.exists() == true){
        Notification note = new Notification(1, this);
            if (overwrite == true){
            try{
                deck.createNewFile(); //recreates the file
                writeDeckToFile(deck); //writes the decks cardlist into the file
                updateDecklist(this.name); //updates the decklist
            }catch (IOException e){
                ErrorWindow error = new ErrorWindow(2);
            }
        }else{
            return;  
        }
    }
}
```

Notification Class:

```
public class Notification extends JFrame {
[...]
public Notification(int key, Deck deck) {
[...]
JButton okayButton = new JButton("Okay");
    okayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
            deck.setOverwrite(true); //sets the decks overwrite boolean true    
        }
    });
    okayButton.setBounds(10, 86, 144, 23);
    contentPane.add(okayButton);

    JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
            deck.setOverwrite(false); //sets the decks overwrite boolean false
        }
    });
```

Sooo...yeah...would be nice if someone could give me some advice here.

Comment: You need a modal dialog. See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details. Also avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: I was going to close it with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008090/send-data-to-previous-jframe) answered by @MadProgrammer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah I got 200+ hits for "modal dialog" just from my answers :P